# Adding a common header and authentication system to a folder of thousands of linked HTML files

Tags: php, linux, apache, mod-rewrite, laravel

I have a folder that is basically an archive of thousands of related webpages in HTML format.  Think of it as a book or sorts, they are all linked together -- but there are no common PHP includes within these files.

What I would like to do is wrap these pages in bootstrap and possibly add in some simple authentication.  Possibly throw them into the Laravel Framework somehow.

This could be accomplished by editing EVERY one of these 5,000+ files and adding a PHP include, but I'm wondering if there is a better way?  Some way to use a common header or framework and then just use these existing page structure, complete with links in the body section somehow.  Possibly with mod_rewrite?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First move those files out side of the DOCUMENT_ROOT so they are not accessible by the public then just use a php file to display the content by wrapping the html file.

```
$htmlfile = 'some.html';

authentication_header();

include_once($htmlfile);

footer();
```